# x64 PC cannot connect to Salesforce from classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, salesforce

I can connect to Salesforce using classic ASP on my x86 computer, but when I try to connect on my x64 (Windows 7) PC, I get error:  "ActiveX component can't create object".

The code I use is:
    Set SforceApi = server.CreateObject("SForceOfficeToolkit4.SForceSe​ssion4")

I downloaded and installed the Office Toolkit.  Also copied the "SF_MSApi4.dll" into the "sysWOW64" folder and registered it there using "regsvr32.exe".  (also tried in the System32 folder).

I have NO problem connecting the x64 PC to Salesforce with following VBA (from word doc):
        Set g_sfApi = New SForceOfficeToolkitLib4.SForceSession4

Just can't get it to work on the x64 in Classic ASP.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: In your ASP code, try `CreateObject` rather than `Server.CreateObject`.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Tom.  Unfortunately, still no connection.  But Anthony posted the solution ... need to change IIS server to enable 32-bit applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open IIS Manager and find the application pool that ASP application runs in.  Open the advanced settings and set to true the "Enable 32-bit applications" setting.

Comment: Thank you!! Changing the IIS Manager to enable 32-bit applications worked.  

(I have to do similar thing connect to the Acrobat FDF toolkit, so I should have known better.)